# If LOOP function but error (Statement invalid outside type block)

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I am doing a IF Loop function.
My data is in column "AA" and i want to return the value in column "BZ".

What I'm trying to look for,

1. if "Delivery Type" = "ZPS" in column "AA", it will return value "5" in Column "BZ".
2. if "Delivery Type" = "L4" in column "AA", it will return value "20" in Column "BZ".

And the results will fill to the last row.

Below is my code:

```
Dim i2 As Long
ZPS As Integer
L4 As Integer
lr2 As Long

Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccrualsWorking")

lr2 = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

For i2 = lr2 To 3 Step -1

    If ws3.Cells(i2, "AA").Value = ZPS Then
            ws3.Range("BZ").Value = 5

    ElseIf ws3.Cells(i, "AA").Value = L4 Then
            ws3.Range("BZ").Value = 20
Next i2
```

Above is my code but it gave me error message: Statement invalid outside Type block.

Comment: I can't see `End If`? Also variable declarations seem erroneus.

Comment: L4 and ZPS have no value so kinda hard to compare with them, no? Also best to mention where the error occurs in your code in your question.

Comment: While I did say "no value", they do have a base 0-value as an integer but I doubt that's what OP wanted. Just as a clarification so I don't confuse future readers.

Comment: @Arvo - yikes. what a bummer. i did not put the "Dim". let me try it out update here once i have gotten the desired results.

Comment: @Notus_Panda - L4 and ZPS do have value. L4 = 20 and ZP2 = 5

Comment: In your code you're declaring them as Integer but nowhere in your code are you giving those variables a value so with the code you showed us, they're remaining 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input and I managed to get the results. Here is my latest and working code.

```vb
Dim i2 As Long
Dim ZPS As Integer
Dim L4 As Integer
Dim lr2 As Long
 
L4 = 20
ZPS = 5
    
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccrualsWorking")
     
    lr2 = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
    
        For i2 = lr2 To 3 Step -1
           
            If ws3.Cells(i2, "AA").Value = "L4" Then
                    ws3.Cells(i2, "BZ").Value = 20
            ElseIf ws3.Cells(i2, "AA").Value = "ZPS" Then
                    ws3.Cells(i2, "CA").Value = 5
            End If
        
        Next i2
```

Comment: If you want to compare with a variable, don't put it between quotes, i.e. `If ws3.Cells(i2,"AA").Value = L4`. Also, don't select an answer as correct if it's not, would be terribly confusing for future readers since you want to compare to 20 and 5 respectively and vbakim declares two string variables, doesn't use them and compares to two strings instead of the 20 and 5 values.